# IBM Object Storage Command Line Access

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using this [guide](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/using-swift-command-line-object-storage), I have been trying to access my containers at IBM Object Storage, I have installed the python-swiftclient library and running this command(AUTH_URL, USERNAME,KEY are from IBM Bluemix Object Storage Credentials Section):

```
swift -A <AUTH_URL> -U <USERNAME> -K <KEY> stat -v
```

I get the following error:

```
Auth GET failed: https://identity.open.softlayer.com/ 300 Multiple Choices  [first 60 chars of response] {"versions": {"values": [{"status": "stable", "updated": "20
```

I have tried with other credentials as well, looked online, no luck so far. What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the Cloud Object Storage (S3 compatible version) look at https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-python.html instead. The example in the KnowledgeLayer is for the SWIFT based option. The new Cloud Object Storage is using S3 API style commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
swift \
  --os-auth-url=https://identity.open.softlayer.com/v3 \
  --auth-version=3 \
  --os-project-id=<projectId> \
  --os-region-name=<region> \
  --os-username=<username> \
  --os-password=<password> \
  --os-user-domain-id=<domainId> \
  stat -v
```

You will find the values for projectId, region, username, password, domainId in the credentials section of your Object Storage service in the Bluemix dashboard.

Another option is to set the environment variables `OS_AUTH_URL`, `OS_AUTH_VERSION`, `OS_PROJECT_ID`, `OS_REGION_NAME`, `OS_USERNAME` (or `OS_USER_ID`), `OS_PASSWORD` and `OS_DOMAIN_ID`.

Comment: I now get this: Auth GET failed: identity.open.softlayer.com/v3 200 OK [first 60 chars of response] {"version": {"status": "stable", "updated": "2015-03-30T00:0 – and_apo 33 mins ago